# Prove that $ \Phi(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T=I $ if $\Phi$ has more columns than rows

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, linear-regression

In linear regression, for a data set $\bar t$, the least-squares solution of the equation $\bar t = \Phi\bar w$ is $$\hat{\bar w} = (\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T\bar t$$ where $\Phi$ is the design matrix and $\bar w$ is the weight vector.

When the number of data points is greater than the number of weights (i.e. the case when **number of rows is lesser than the number of columns** of $\Phi$), we can choose weights such that the data points are fitted exactly, i.e.
$$\begin{align*}\bar t &= \Phi \hat{\bar w}\\
&= \Phi(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T\bar t
\end{align*}$$

---

Clearly, $$\Phi(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T = I$$ when number of rows of $\Phi$ is lesser than the number of columns of $\Phi$. But how can this be proved? I tried writing $I = (\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}(\Phi^T\Phi)$ but that took me nowhere.

**Edit:** Let us assume that $\Phi$ has full rank (all rows linearly independent).

Comment: Having more columns than rows is not sufficient; in this case the matrix still may fail to be full rank, in which case the inverse is not defined. For the full-rank case, look up Singular Value decomposition.

Comment: If $\Phi$ were square you could say $\Phi(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T=\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\Phi^T)^{-1})\Phi^T=I$

Comment: This isn't quite true as written: Suppose $\Phi$ has just two rows which are both identical. Then $\Phi$ trivially has a zero eigenvalue, therefore $\Phi^\top \Phi$ does as well and is not invertible. What you presumably need to further assume is that $\Phi$ has full rank, which in the present case (more columns than rows) means that the rows are all linearly independent.

Comment: @Semiclassical Good point. Let us assume that the rows are linearly independent. I've edited the question.

Comment: @MikeHawk I tried using SVD, for $\Phi = U\Sigma V^T$, I got $\Phi(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T = U\Sigma(\Sigma^T\Sigma)\Sigma^T U^T$. How to proceed after that?

Comment: Something is strange: If $\Phi$ is an $n \times m$ matrix with $n<m$ (more rows than columns) then $\Phi$ is full rank when it has rank $n$. But $\Phi^\top \Phi$ has the same rank as $\Phi$ itself, and it's an $m\times m$ matrix. Hence $\Phi^\top \Phi$ cannot be full rank (and so is not invertible) when $\Phi$ has more rows than columns.

Comment: Take $\Phi=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, all rows are linearly independent but $\Phi^T\Phi$ is not invertible. Are you sure you don't mix up rows and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceeding as in your comment, write $\Phi=U\Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal, and $\Sigma$ is rectangular-diagonal with non-negative entries along the diagonal. Plugging into $\Phi(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T$ and simplifying $U\Sigma (\Sigma^T\Sigma)^{-1}\Sigma^TU^T$. Note that $(\Sigma^T\Sigma)^{-1}$ is diagonal with diagonal with entries $1/\sigma_i^2$, with $\sigma_i$ being the diagonal elements of $\Sigma$. Thus an easy computation shows that  $\Sigma (\Sigma^T\Sigma)^{-1}\Sigma^T=I$ and the desired result follows.